# Why is `9.3 == 9.3.to_d` false?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, decimal, precision

I just ran into an interesting case during TDD:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(MoneyManager::CustomsCalculator.call(price: 31,    weight: 1.12)).to    eq 9.3

   expected: 9.3
        got: 0.93e1
```

I investigated further and found:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
 => true
2.4.2 :005 > require 'bigdecimal/util'
 => true
...
2.4.2 :008 > 1 == 1.to_d
 => true
2.4.2 :009 > 2 == 2.to_d
 => true
2.4.2 :010 > 2.0 == 2.0.to_d
 => true
2.4.2 :011 > 1.3 == 1.3.to_d
 => true
2.4.2 :012 > 9.3 == 9.3.to_d
 => false
```

Why is `9.3 == 9.3.to_d` `false`?

PS, I am well aware of what a Float and a BigDecimal is, but I'm delightfully puzzled by this particular behavior.

Comment: you should never do equality testing with floating point values.  You always have to deal with inaccurate internal representation issues with Float, so == and != aren't terribly useful. if you check the difference `1.3.to_d - 1.3` you will see that it will be not exactly 0

Comment: As hotfix stated. `(f1 - f2).abs < EPSILON` is the traditional way to compare floats. Using equality will only lead to tears. This method is also nicer to the machine running the code.

Comment: This behavior is also not just for `bigdecimal`. I do a lot of interop with Ruby and packed strings. `[0.123].pack('f').unpack('f')  #=> 0.12300000339746475` Using `==` is quite worthless. But if using an epsilon value with say 7 digits of precision `0.0000001`, the result is as expected.

Comment: `9.3 == 9.3.to_d.to_f #=> true` 

Comment: Maybe it's a off-by-one error regarding BigDecimal's default precision of [`Float::DIG`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Float.html#DIG) (which is `15`): `9.3 == 9.3.to_d(15) #=> false` vs. `9.3 == 9.3.to_d(16) #=> true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a "ruby problem". This is a *floating point representation of numbers* problem.

You cannot *reliably* perform an equality check between floating point numbers and the "exact" value (as represented by `BigDecimal`).

`BigDecimal.new(9.3, 2)` is exact. `9.3` is not.

```
9.3 * 100 #=> 930.0000000000001
1.3 * 100 #=> 130.0
```

That's just how binary floating point numbers work. They are (sometimes) an inexact representation of the "true" value.

You can either:

- Compare like-for-like (`bigdecimal1 == bigdecimal2`, or `float1 == float2`). But also note that comparing `float1 == float2` is also unreliable if you're performing different calculations to get those values!! Or,
- Check that the values are equal *within an error bound* (e.g. in `rspec` terms, `expect(value1).to be_within(1e-12).of(value2)`).

Comment: This promulgates an incorrect model of floating-point. The statement “They are inexact” is false. (They are also not limited to being finite or being binary.) As specified in IEEE 754, a floating-point number represents one number exactly. Instead, operations are defined to return mathematical results rounded to the nearest representable vallues. This, floating-point numbers are exact, but operations may be inexact. Understanding this distinction is crucial for reasoning about floating-point comoutation correctly and for designing comoutations.

Comment: Ironically, comparing floating-point values for equality is always exact yet is the most frequently (and incorrectly) said to be unreliable. Comparing for equality returns true if and only if the two items compared are exactly equal. If it returns false when a user desires it return true, that is because there has been an error earlier, not an error in the comparison. And that shows why blaming either comparing for equality or saying floating-point numbers are inaccurate is misleading: They falsely lead people to look for a problem in the comparison when the problem is actually elsewhere.

Comment: When I said "they are inexact", I meant "they are (sometimes) an inexact way to represent *the value you truly mean*". So for example, the floating point representation of `9.3` is does not **actually** mean `9.3`. (It's `9.300000000000001`.) My answer also did state that comparing `float1 == float2` is valid, but it's a risky strategy since you could get a subtle/virtually untraceable error in some cases.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the _representation_ is already inexact. Instead of the actual value (9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125), we see an approximation (9.3).

Comment: @Stefan: The fact that 9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125 is formatted for display (with default settings) as “9.3” does not mean it represents 9.3. As I wrote, IEEE 754 is clear on this; a floating-point object set to 9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125 represents 9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125 exactly and does not represent 9.3. When arithmetic operations are performed on it, it will behave as if it is 9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125, and it will not generally behave as if it were 9.3.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't say that the float 9.3 is equivalent to the real number 9.3. I said that its representation (i.e. "9.3") is already an approximation (and therefore inexact).

Comment: @Stefan: This is an incorrect model of floating-point. The binary floating-point value 9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125 **is not a representation of 9.3**. You write, of 9.3, “its representation (i.e. "9.3") is already an approximation. But that is wrong. 9.3 has **no representation at all** in binary floating-point. When “9.3” is converted from source text or input text or from decimal 9.3, a **conversion operation** is performed. Such conversion operations are defined in IEEE 754. If performed correctly, the result is 9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125…

Comment: This result is, according to IEEE 754, exactly the number 9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125 and is not a representation of 9.3. Understanding this distinction is crucial to reasoning about floating-point arithmetic. If one is to write proofs about floating-point operations or to deduce error bounds or to engineer code to obtain desired results, then one must understand this distinction and use the properties of floating-point objects and operations correctly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you get me wrong. I meant it to be the other way 'round. "9.3" is the way 9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125 is represented (or displayed). And _that_ conversion for displaying purposes is the approximation I'm talking about.

Comment: @Stefan: Formatting for display has nothing to do with the value represented for arithmetic. It does not affect how arithmetic proceeds. The string produced is merely for the convenience of humans. And it is only the default formatting that produces “9.3”. The exact value can be produced on demand. The string “9.3” should be understood to be only the result of a conversion with rounding.

Comment: @EricPostpischil _"the result of a conversion with rounding"_ – that's what I [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724802/why-is-9-3-9-3-to-d-false/51725262?noredirect=1#comment90455059_51725262) initially: _"Instead of the actual value, we see an approximation"_.

Comment: @Stefan: The thing is, the result of an operation is not a representation of the original number. If you add two to a number, negate a number, or take the cosine of a number, the result is a new number. It is not a representation of the original number. The same is true of conversion to decimal with rounding to limited precision. The result is generally a new number. People are tempted to think of it as a representation of the original because it is close and because languages are bad about communicating proper floating-point semantics, but it is not. An operation has been performed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil When a user writes `9.3`, they probably expect it to mean `9.3`, not `9.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125`. The "operation being performed" (storing the value as a floating point) is invisible. Therein lies the confusion. That's what we mean when saying "floating points are inexact". Yes, a floating point does represent a specific value, *but* it's not (always) the exact value that the user typed into the code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil with "representation" I mean the way a float is being represented, i.e. its "display value". If something shows as 9.3 I'm tempted to think that it means 9.3 (of course). But since I know how floats work and how they are displayed, I think of 9.3 as an approximation of its actual value. When I say _"the float 9.3 is inaccurate"_ I mean _"9.3 is not its actual value"_. Or, in a more general sense: _"floats are inaccurate"_ by which I mean _"watch out, the value a float pretends to be (the one you see) might not be its actual value"_.

Comment: @Stefan: Please do not do that. You can find good information on thinking about floating-point arithmetic in [*Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic* by Muller *et al*](http://a.co/ia2cFuo). It is expensive, but, if that is a barrier, I expect you can find other textbooks. Or online sources, but so many of them are poorly written.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited due to Eric comment above**

You could use the nature of float and compare it to to a limit you propose which would return either `true` or `false` reliably.

```
(bigdecimal-float).abs < comparison_limit
```

In your example that would be (I have added () to improve readability):

```
((9.3.to_d)-9.3).abs < 0.000001  <-- watch out for the limit!
```

Which yields `true` and can be used for testing.

**Edit** based on Eric's (thank you for it) comment.
It is important to always check the limits of the tolerance when comparing the two numbers.

You could do it the following way:

```
9.3.next_float
```

which would give you

```
9.300000000000002
```

so your tolerance should be

```
0.000000000000002
```

Note: watch out for the step:

```
9.3.next_float.next_float
=> 9.300000000000004
```

Now the code looks differently:

```
((9.3.to_d)-9.3).abs < 0.000000000000002
```

Comment: Comparing with a tolerance decreases false negatives at the expense of increasing false positives. So code like this can introduce new bugs into software.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right in general case.  If I quote your above comment "operations are defined to return mathematical results rounded to the nearest representable values".  If you use the set tolerance as maximum representable value then your code does not need to increase false positives (no new bugs introduced).

Comment: The maximum representable value in IEEE-754 floating-point is infinity. Setting the tolerance to infinity would of course create a massive bug in a program. I am not sure what other value you might have meant. The errors in a sequence of floating-point computations may compound or cancel, depending on both the nature of the algorithm and the particular data. So there is no general rule for what tolerance to set. Some algorithms naturally converge, and the tolerance could be set to 1 ULP. Some algorithms diverge, and the expected errors could be infinite.

Comment: In any case, in any normal situation, comparing with a tolerance will admit false negatives. It is inevitable: If the code is modified to accept as equal numbers that would be equal if computed with exact mathematics but that differ due to being computed with limited precision, then the code will also accept as equal numbers that would be unequal if computed with exact mathematics but that are close. No person should accept the advice to compare with a tolerance and put it into their code without evaluating the adverse effects it causes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "evaluating the adverse effects it causes" - You are right that should be considered for any code added.  Since computers (hw, cpu, etc.) are, by the nature, limited machines for that they have also limited precision.   Each platform (Intel, Risc/V, etc.) will have different precision and that should be definitely be taken in account when writing such code.